# Open new file for every n element

Tags: python, json, loops, for-loop

I have *n* batches, each containing 100 API requests. Batch 1 contains files [1-100], batch 2 contains files [101-200] etc...

I want to dump each of these into a json file. This is fine.. However, I want to dump 100k json responses into 1 file, then create a new file and dump the next 100k observations into another file.

I need to configure a function which creates a file based on batch number, I have tried the following:

```
def open_file(self, batch):
    if batch % 1000 == 0:
        filename = f"data_{batch}.json"
    else:
        filename = ""
    
    f = open(filename, "a")
    return f
```

If batch % 1000 == 0, then I want to change the name (as batch number 1000 -> 1000 batches of 100 json requests = 100k in total). However, this clearly does not work as when I evaluate batch 1001, the old file opens again. How can I create one file for batch 1-999, another file for batch 1000-1999, then for 2000-2999....?

Thanks

### Edit: additional information

```
def fetch_data(self, sequence, batch=1):
    # fetch event list (event list size = 100)
    event_list = self.events(sequence)

    # open files to store data
    f = self.open_file(batch)

    # opening thread pool executor for multi-threading
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
        # self.thread_event_list multi-threads each event in event list by sending
        # and API request.
        for i, response in enumerate(executor.map(self.thread_event_list, event_list), 1):
            json.dump(response.json(), f)
            f.write("\n")

        # continue from last sequence number (used in the recursive call)
        last_sequence = response.json()["last_sequence"]

        # Recursive call, use last sequence number of the
        # event list, and continue with sequence + 1 and batch +1
        self.fetch_data(
          sequence=last_sequence + 1,
          batch=batch + 1
        )
```

Comment: Please show more of your code and how this function is used to access this file, and what files you actually have so the expected behavior can be understood in reference to the files.

Comment: Edited! See above.

Comment: The function seems dubious as whenever filename is "" it will attempt to open("", "a") which should result in an error. I posted an answer.

Comment: Yep, I was too quick with simplifying the codes, they are fairly long and complicated. It was ment to be: filename = "", then: open(f"data{filename}", "a"). Nevertheless, your code worked fine! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import math

# Be sure that batch is never 0, otherwise this will create a file for batch #0 only.
def open_file(self, batch):

    # If you're unsure, this handles it for you.
    if batch < 1:
        batch = 1

    filename = f"data_{math.ceil(batch/1000)}.json"
    f = open(filename, "a")
    return f
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm. I have to read up on the math.ceil argument.

Comment: The math.ceil function simply rounds up the number. In essence what this does is divide by a thousand, so anything less than a thousand will be 0 < x < 1, rounded up this will always result in 1. The moment batch is larger than 1000 (i.e 1001), it will result in 1.001, which rounded up returns 2, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a range function?
`

```
 if batch in range(1,1000):
     filename = f"data_{batch_name1}.json"
 elif batch in range(1000,2000):
    filename = f"data_{batch_name2}.json"

 elif batch in range(2000,3000):
    filename = f"data_{batch_name3}.json"
```

`

Comment: As I have 33m URL end points, which is continuously expanding every day... it must be more generic, unfortunately. Sorry for not stating.